# TFS "Detect Local Changes" returning spurious filenames

Tags: tfs

Environment: TFS plugin within Eclipse. Android project.

When I select TFS menu item "Detect Local Changes," it lists a bunch of filenames. Each file is displayed twice - once as "Add" and once as "Delete." However, when I run the compare command on the folder, it displays just a couple of files that I had indeed modified.

I am confused. Why this oddity? Is there a way to fix it? Regards.

Comment: Have you moved or renamed the files, and not told TFS? I don't know about TEE, but VS allows you promote a delete and add to a rename, of you did it in the file system.

Comment: What operating system?  Is your filesystem case sensitive?

Comment: Occasionally, my VPN network disconnects. I might have worked offline without realizing. The client is on Windows. The filenames are exactly the same case-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a possible source cause (corrupted TFS cache) and a way to fix it: delete the TFS cache located at `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache`.

(Got this idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19281291/158074) answer - same fix, somewhat distinct problem.)