# Remove TFS mappings

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, source-control-bindings

I am using Visual Studio 2015. Initially I installed TFS 2013 on my local machine with source control mappings to my local User folder. After some time there was a need to include some more developers to my project so I installed TFS 2013 on a server running Windows Server 2012.

Then I **UnBind** my solution from local TFS and tried to add it to the TFS on the server. But it was only taking my local TFS, so I **uninstalled** TFS from my local machine. But then again when I tried to add my solution to the TFS on server, it gives the error shown in the image.[image]

Then I removed my workspaces as mentioned in [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245474(v=vs.90).aspx)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784296/how-to-remove-a-tfs-workspace-mapping) and then restarted my local machine but the error is still there.

Although I am creating the new workspace with exactly same name and place but when I have removed the older workspace and TFS from my local machine, wouldn't the error be removed!

May be TFS marked the workspaces somewhere in Computer registry but I don't know it. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

> AWAIS is my local machine name
>
> awais:8080/tfs was my older TFS that was on my local machine but I
>   already uninstalled it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use [tf command-line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3(v=vs.100).aspx) to remove old workspace which clears cache as well:

  > tf workspaces /remove:* /collection:http://awais:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
- If it does not work, try removing from your connections on Team Explorer, deleting the local folder and   [clearing your cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsalm/archive/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines.aspx)
- Use [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2013) to track the workspace, it is a great tool to manage the workspaces.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked by deleting Cache in C:\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation