# Tfs check out and mapping issue

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs

I am confused with a mapping issue in TFS.  I checked out the projects from TFS into my workspace without creating the TFS folder hierarchy. That is, I directly check out all the projects into my workspace. After that, my boss suggested me to check out the projects as TFS folder hierarchy. I checked out a project based on TFS hierarchy. That is, I  root folders are created and that project checked out inside that. Now I have to move other projects that are directly checked out in the workspace into that root folder. 
how can I do this? So I created a new workspace and tried to check out the code again. But currently, my local path is pointing to previous workspace folder.. how can I change this and fresh check out of those projects...?

Comment: you need to read up on TFS workspaces. Answers to all the things you are asking here can be found in the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/create-work-workspaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your java, eclipse tag, seems you are using [Team Explorer Everywhere Plugin for Eclipse](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere).

Looks like you want to check out the files from TFS server to another(new workspace) instead of the old workspace(already mapped).

Then you need to remove the work folder mapping of your local path:

> 1. View the working folders for your Team Foundation Server workspace.
>      For more information, see [View Team Foundation Server Workspaces and
>      the Working Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753(v=vs.100).aspx#View%20Team%20Foundation%20Server%20Workspaces%20and%20the%20Working%20Folders).
> 2. In the **Working folders** list, right-click the row that corresponds to
>      the working folder mapping that you want to remove, and then click
>      **Delete**.
> 3. Repeat the previous step for any other mappings that you want to
>      remove, and then click OK.

Another way is through  [tf workfolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fa04bx6(v=vs.100).aspx) command from a command prompt

Type `tf workfold -unmap LocalFolder`, and then press ENTER. Replace LocalFolder with the path on your local computer that you mapped to that server folder. More information please refer this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753(v=vs.100).aspx#Add,%20Remove,%20or%20Change%20Working%20Folder%20Mappings) in MSDN.

---

If you don't need the old workspace any more, suggest you directly delete the old workspace in your develop machine. How to do this follow the answer in this question: [How to remove a TFS Workspace Mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784296/how-to-remove-a-tfs-workspace-mapping)